# Probability that a fixed point on a table of radius R and border of width r will be covered given N circular disks of radius r staying on the table

Tags: probability, geometric-probability

Circular discs of radius $r$ are thrown at random on to a plane circular table of radius $R$ which is surrounded by a border of uniform width $r$ lying in the same plane as the table. If the discs are thrown independently and at random, and $N$ stay on the table, show that the probability that a fixed point on the table, but not the border, will be covered is

$$1-\left(1-\frac{r^2}{(R+r)^2}\right)^N$$

[image: circle]
Let D be the fixed point, then circle $HFGE$ with radius $r$ would be the distribution area for the centre of the disk $(N=1)$

Comment: Any ideas to get started?

Comment: Do you agree with the outcome in special case $N=1$?

Comment: It took a while to figure out what the question actually means. According to my understanding it is given that N disks has fallen on to the table when randomly thrown. We need to find the probability that a fixed point within the table borders will be covered by them

Comment: @drhab N=1 could be a good start

Comment: @drhab With N=1 the solution is pretty simple. finding the distribution of centre of the disk around the fixed point say A. The probability being the ratio of the areas

Comment: So apparantly $\frac{r^2}{(R+r)^2}$ equals the probability that a disk will cover the fixed point on the table but not the border. Then $1-\frac{r^2}{(R+r)^2}$ equals the probability that a disk will *not* do that. Then $(1-\frac{r^2}{(R+r)^2})^N$ equals the probability that $N$ disks will *not* do that. Then $1-(1-\frac{r^2}{(R+r)^2})^N$ equals the probability that at least one of $N$ disks will do that.

Comment: @drhab yeah, you are correct. That was perfect explanation! thankyou